# Implementing a model for "teams" in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to implement a team feature in django 1.8. (Team as in sports team)

Every user can join up to one team at a time and a team thus can hold many users. Now i am unsure how to define my models.py

I started with this core, but now i am unsure how to make the connection of Team<->User

```
from django.db import models

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1024)
    logo = models.ImageField()

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Player(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    team = ForeignKey('Team')
```

Do I now create a second class user_team or do I just add the team as a foreign key to the user? (and if thats the way where would i need to do this?)

Thanks,

Wegi

// edit: I added some code at the bottom. Would this Player model be enough to define the relationship?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `team_id = model`?

Comment: Oh I copied the wrong version, thanks for noticing.

Comment: Have you set up a [user profile model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)?

Comment: I haven't. Looking at the link you gave me i do not fully understand how i can use that for my problem, sorry. I Would appreciate if you could elaborate more. Thank you.

Comment: I added some code and an explanation. Is this how the user profile model is supposed to work? Is this enough for my needs?

Comment: if your `Player` has no extra fields, I'd highly suggest only keep one `Team` model and make `player` as a **ManyToMany** field in it, referencing `User`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Anzel. Does that also work if i want every player only to join one team at a time?

Comment: @WeGi, you can implement a `TeamManager` along your `Team` and add whatever method like `add_player()` and put all the logics/checking in it.

Comment: WeGi, yes that should do it. @Anzel, indeed but the need for extra fields may come later and having a `ForeignKey` enforces the unicity of the relation at database level which will simplify the code and be less error prone.

Comment: @WeGi, if you are satisfied with your solution, you may post an answer to it and accept it.

Comment: @aumo, that's what I meant in previous comment -- if no extra fields. If extra fields are needed in future, cutom `UserProfile` or an intermediate `ManyToMany` models should suffice.

Comment: @WeGi, although you have already found your solution. I have posted an alternative for your reference, that I will consider using with `ManyToMany`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this use case, I will still suggest an alternative using a `ManyToMany` field, with an intermediate model and model manager.

A quick sample structure looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1024)
    logo = models.ImageField()
    players = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Player')


class PlayerManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def add_player(self, user, team):
        # ... your code here ...

    def remove_player(self, user, team):
        # ... your code here ...

    def trasnfer_player(self, user, team):
        # ... your code here ...


class Player(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    other_fields = #...

    objects = PlayerManager()
```

Usage:

```
Player.objects.add_player(user, team, *other_fields)
```

You will then be able to get `User` related `Team`, for example:

```
team_with_user = Team.objects.filter(players__name="hello")
user_in_team = User.objects.filter(team__name="world")
```

**Note**: I haven't tested the code, so please correct me if I make any mistake above.

The reason why I prefer this way is to abstract away your database logic into application. So in future if there is a need for allowing `User` joining multiple teams, you can just change the application logic to allow it through the manager.

Comment: @WeGi, I'm glad you like this. Yes I like structuring my app in a more flexible way and try to use app layer to implement relationship. So to avoid some possible future migration hell, and trust me, your database admin (if any) is going to love you being a developer.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @aumo I solved the problem by adding a user profile model like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Player(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    team = models.ForeignKey('Team')
```

I chose this solution over adding teams as a ManyToMany field inside the Teams class because I am not sure if any more field need to be added to the Player during development.

Thanks to everybody for your help.